# 2D Bicubic Splines with scattered data

Tags: interpolation, spline, alglib

Is there any library (DLL) or c# code which allows to interpolate 2D scattered data? Algib is pretty good but works with regular grids

Answer (score 1):

[Alglib fastrbf](http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/fastrbf.php)
has 2 algorithms:

1. "RBF-ML can be used to solve two kinds of problems: interpolation problems and smoothing problems with controllable noise suppression"
2. "RBF-QNN uses automatic radius selection."

(I haven't used either, and
[Gaussian RBFs tend to be ill-conditioned](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7561/do-rbf-kernel-matrices-tend-to-be-ill-conditioned),
but the doc looks reasonable.)

And please add tag "alglib".

Answer (score 0):

ALGLIB now also offers cubic spline interpolation of scattered data. We have made good experiences with the [spline2d method](https://www.alglib.net/interpolation/bicubic-spline-interpolation-fitting.php#header2) using the BlockLLS solver. It is, however, necessary to tune the number of grid points to a not too large value, otherwise the interpolant shows artifacts.